# Decompiler and repacker for .NET

Tags: c#, decompiler, dotpeek

Is there a tool which allows me to decompile a .net dll, edit it and repack it back to dll again?

I use dotPeek a lot. It can't repack or edit.

Comment: What do you want to decompile, edit and repack?

Comment: @MattHouser: winform dll, I wish to enable some user control like checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Reflector is cool - but it's not free.

There is [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) - which is a lower level tool that can modify assemblies.  The two I now use most often are:

[JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Comment: JustDecopile is AWESOME! I can generate project now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) is one of a kind. I have successfully created c# projects from binaries and recompiled them.

Bear in mind that protected assemblies are difficult to decompile, also they may be obfuscated or protected against ILDASM.